# Android - Push up layout when EditText has focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Before starting, I am sorry for the bad English, i'm French.

I have a main activity, which is a navigation bar (ActionBarActivity) whit a DrawerLayout. From this DrawerLayout, I start different Fragment, and one of them has a ViewPager.
I have 3 tab, so 3 Fragment inside. In this 3 Fragment I have a ListView, and when i click on item, an other Fragment take the place of the current Fragment on the tab.
On this new Fragment i have some elements, but the problem become from EditText. The EditText open the keyboard but i can't see what i'm tapping because he is under the keyboard.
I think the problem is the ViewPager, because when I use this Fragment from the navigation menu, I haven't this problem.

I have already try to use ScrollView, and this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

There is my ViewPager xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.neden.neden.CustomViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vpPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</com.neden.neden.CustomViewPager>
```

Comment: I could give you that works exactly like facebook if you are interested. Check how facebook works at its login on a small screen device and if that is what you are looking I am more than happy to post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in forum, found a solution but now, i havent notification bar.

I use this code in my main activity :

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

If you have an other solution, ...